# Prevent Closing as duplicate when the duplicate has no accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

There is very bad situation when a question was asked and it was not asked well enough or
had no enough interest long time ago, the question was not answered.

Now I want to ask a new question that is similar but not exact duplicate.

It is got closed as "exact duplication" and the Duplicate has no answer!

See: [GetEnvironmentStrings and stange values "=::=::\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782435/getenvironmentstrings-and-stange-values)

I wanted to provide a bounty on this question the way it asks (not the other duplicate ones).

I think the questions that are marked as "exact duplicate" should not be closed
if the duplicate question has not accepted answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The criteria for closing a question as a duplicate is focused *solely* on the content of the two questions.

If another question asks exactly the same thing (or, by the judgment of 5 trusted community members, very nearly the same thing) as yours, then your question is subject to being closed as a duplicate of that other "master" question.

Whether the question has been *answered* or not is completely irrelevant. That doesn't make your question not a duplicate, it just means that the original question hasn't been answered yet.

If you'd like to encourage someone to answer it, you can set a bounty on the original "master" question. There is nothing keeping you from setting a bounty on someone else's question. In fact, that's encouraged—you even get a badge for it.

However, [in this particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431689/what-are-these-strange-environment-variables), a bounty seems unnecessary. [Raymond Chen already answered it in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431689/what-are-these-strange-environment-variables#comment13465334_10431689) with a link to his blog post on the same topic. [Tim Pietzcker tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431689/what-are-these-strange-environment-variables#comment13465610_10431689) to encourage him to post that as an actual answer, but [Raymond rightly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431689/what-are-these-strange-environment-variables#comment13465655_10431689) that [it's not, in itself, answer because it is only a link to an external resource](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). He says that if someone finds his relevant blog article helpful, they should post their own answer to the question and link to his blog post for reference. That person could be you!

Answer (score 4):

> There is very bad situation when a question was asked and it was not asked well enough or had no enough interest long time ago, the question was not answered.

One of the great features of the StackExchange platform is in the editing features. Any user can suggest an edit to improve a question or answer. In fact, with over 13k reputation in your profile on StackOverflow, your edits will go through right away.

When a question is edited, the dust blows off, and it is bumped back up to the top of the active page.

Therefore, there is no need to post a duplicate. In fact, you could even wait a few days to see if it gets answered and *then* post a bounty if it still doesn't get enough attention. ;)