# Does flagging a question as duplicate require that the original must have an answer?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, flag-dialog

Today was my first attempt at flagging a question as a duplicate. When I stepped through the flagging wizard, I noticed the comment below the "duplicate" choice that says "This question has been asked before and already has an answer."

Does flagging a question as a duplicate really require that the original must have an answer?

[This answer on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133956/177757) says that it is not so, and that only the content of the questions is relevant. But then, why does the flagging wizard contain the comment quoted above? Am I too strict and should just accept the comment as a guideline instead of as a hard rule?

If it is of any interest, the questions I am talking about can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121639/why-doesnt-my-pushviewcontroller-not-work), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116981/why-does-my-pushviewcontroller-not-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123898/why-doesnt-my-pushviewcontroller-work). At the time of writing, none of the questions has an accepted answer, or an answer that seems to solve the problem.

Comment: This is interesting all three are on the same day, have very similar codes, have similar tone/writing style, have similar deadlines, *but* different user account.

Comment: Super meta. This question about closing dupes was marked as a possible dupe, to a question with no accepted answer. Woah.

Comment: It's allowed on Meta @EJC :-). Otherwise you wouldn't be able to close bug reports as a duplicate of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules around closing duplicates (and the wording) were changed not too long ago, see: [Changes to "close as duplicate" (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux).

In short, yes, the duplicate must have an answer. There are exceptions (notably for questions from the same person to prevent re-posts), but the main idea is that the user should find an answer, not just another similar un-answered question.

Comment: I'm glad to see the exception about questions from the same user!

Answer (score -4):

**Nope.**

As long as the questions are the same then your good to go.