# Duplicate questions with no accepted answer

Tags: support, flags, answers, accepted-answer

What am I supposed to do when trying to flag a question as a duplicate but the question I'm trying to link doesn't have an accepted answer?

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133955/prevent-closing-as-duplicate-when-the-duplicate-has-no-accepted-answer) and the answer makes me think that I should be able to flag it even with no accepted answer.

> The criteria for closing a question as a duplicate is focused solely on the content of the two questions.
>
> If another question asks exactly the same thing (or, by the judgment of 5 trusted community members, very nearly the same thing) as yours, then your question is subject to being closed as a duplicate of that other "master" question.
>
> Whether the question has been answered or not is completely irrelevant. That doesn't make your question not a duplicate, it just means that the original question hasn't been answered yet.

But if I actually try I get `This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer`.

So what's the deal? Was this changed or should I still be able to flag it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does duplicate closing work? When is a question a duplicate, and how should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-does-duplicate-closing-work-when-is-a-question-a-duplicate-and-how-should) Specifically the section under heading **Should I flag for moderator attention?**

Comment: I guess, basically flag for moderator attention.

Comment: At the time the question you link to was asked, the restriction against closing a question as a duplicate of an unanswered question didn't exist yet. This was [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) less than a year later.